# significance of an word in a sentence

Tags: prepositions, pronouns

Can anyone tell me how is "to" changing the meaning of the sentence below ?

"whom did you give that letter to?"

and what is the difference between following sentences or B,C is grammatically wrong:

a)whom did you give that letter to?

b)whom did you give that letter?

c)who did you give that letter to?

d)who did you give that letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whom did you give that letter to?
>
> whom did you give that letter?
>
> who did you give that letter to?
>
> who did you give that letter?

I'm not going to get into the whole who/whom thing since it's been [asked many times](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=who+whom).  The short answer is that you should avoid using "whom" since "who" is perfectly acceptable substitute in contemporary English.

You do need a "to" somewhere in the sentence, so the second and fourth examples are incorrect.  This, however, opens the can of worms that is [the question of whether it is OK to end a sentence with a preposition.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=end+sentence+preposition)  If you buy into this rule (that you must not end a sentence with a preposition), and you really want to use *whom*. then you can instead say:

> To whom did you give that letter?

Otherwise the meaning doesn't change, whether you say "who" or "whom".

Comment: Blanket advice like _you should avoid using "whom" since "who" is perfectly acceptable substitute in contemporary English"_ is ... er, ill-advised. In any kind of formal or academic writing, **The person to who you gave it** will make the writer sound a right boob.

Answer (score 2):

Your second sentence, "Whom did you give that letter?", is not proper English.

Another way to say "Whom did you give that letter to?" is "To whom did you give that letter?".  It shows more clearly that "to" is a preposition, and "to whom" is the prepositional phrase.

I could answer the question by saying "I gave the letter to somebody".  I could not answer the question by saying "I gave the letter somebody."  The 'to' is necessary.